# virtualbox error when updating system

Tags: virtualbox

I was just wondering, has anyone had this problem before??
This happens when I try to do apt-get upgrade or install new software through terminal. I would like to note that virtualbox works.. How can I check kwhich dependencies are needed ???  apt-get update -f doesn't help

Thanks in advance

```
Setting up virtualbox (4.3.26-dfsg-2ubuntu2) ...
insserv: script virtualbox: service vboxdrv already provided!
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status     1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox-qt:
 virtualbox-qt depends on virtualbox (= 4.3.26-dfsg-2ubuntu2); however:
  Package virtualbox is not configured yet.
Package virtualbox-4.3 which provides virtualbox is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-qt (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox-dkms:
virtualbox-dkms depends on virtualbox (>= 4.3.26-dfsg-2ubuntu2); however:
Package virtualbox is not configured yet.
Package virtualbox-4.3 which provides virtualbox is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-dkms (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
    No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
            Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox
 virtualbox-qt
 virtualbox-dkms
 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: try to run command `sudo apt-get -f install `    then upgrade

Answer (score -1):

Using the command `apt-cache depends <package-name>` should tell you which dependencies are needed on a package.